# javax.mail.MessagingException: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized while trying to send an email

Tags: java, email

I generally just want to send a simply email using a new created gmx mail account. If I try to use the code on a friend's laptop it's unexpectedly working. Although it's not working on my laptop and I just get following error message.

```
Logged in
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
Sending ...
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=mail.gmx.net, user=*name of PC user*, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.gmx.net", port 587, isSSL false
220 gmx.net (mrgmx005) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.gmx.net", port: 465
EHLO *name of PC*
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized
HELO *name of PC*
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized    

javax.mail.MessagingException: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2324)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:1678)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:746)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at touristoffice.Main.btnSendEmail(Main.java:1538)
at touristoffice.Main.lambda$18(Main.java:1272)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I also correctly imported all neccessary classes as well as libaries. The method which should be able to create this sending email is as follow:

```
private static void btnSendEmail(ActionEvent e) throws MessagingException, Exception {
    
    final String user = "...@gmx.at";
    final String password = "***********";
    final String smtpHost = "mail.gmx.net";
    final String smtpPort = "587";
    final String sslPort = "465";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", sslPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    };

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    System.out.println("Logged in");

    String sender = "...@gmx.at";
    String receiver = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the receiver of the message");
    String subject = "Subject";
    String message = "text";

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
    msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
    msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(sender, false));
    msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(receiver, false));

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(message, "UTF-8");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    msg.setContent(multipart);

    System.out.println("Sending ...");
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

I would be very glad if there is anybody who could find a solution to my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the trace it looks like the `helo` command was not working, which would be weird, as this is a basic SMTP verb. Is there a firewall that could mess with the traffic? Try to enable more debugging output. Try to connect manually (`telnet mail.gmx.net 25`, then enter "helo ...", or try "ehlo ..." (extended helo)). Or capture the dialog with wireshark. If you use plain smtp, change the port to 25.

Comment: More debugging outpout has been added.